# how to check the previous row in a 2D array? in Python

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, multidimensional-array

6/12/20: edited post after commenters made it clear that I didn't provide enough info in OP.

Suppose that I have a tsv file (named "tsv-test.txt") with the following contents:

```
5ig7    G   H   0   I
5ig7    A   B   0   C
5ig7    D   E   0   F
5ig7    J   K   0   L
6ch8    D   E   0   B
```

In the first column, I want to check if the previous row has the same term.  I've read the tsv into a list-of-lists.  how do I loop through the list-of-lists to do this check at every row for the term in the first column?  For reference, here's what I've done so far:

```
import csv

#read the tsv into python, tell python its a tsv
tsv_file = open("tsv-test.txt")
read_tsv = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t")

#put tsv into a 2D array
arraytest = []
for line in read_tsv:
    arraytest.append(line)
```

I'd like to loop through the arraytest variable with a true/false statement. I don't know how to write this code, but hopefully what I'm trying to do comes across below:

```
if arraytest[n][0] == arraytest[n-1][0]:
    print("True")
else:
    print("False")
```

The output I'm expecting is:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: Which term of the previous row? Give an example of when the if statement is True

Comment: Add a new variable that always holds the value of the last loop interation and then compare with the current one?

Comment: Is this a 2d numpy array, or a list of lists? From the code I'd assume the latter. And what would you like to do with a found duplicate?

Comment: Additional info added for @JanChristophTerasa

Comment: Additional info added for @MrNobody33

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
import csv

#read the tsv into python, tell python its a tsv
tsv_file = open("tsv-test.txt")
read_tsv = list(csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t"))

for i,line in enumerate(read_tsv):
    if i == 0:continue     
    print(read_tsv[i][0] == read_tsv[i-1][0])
```

Output:

```
True
True
True
False
```

Comment: how is that that 'print(read_tsv[i][0] == read_tsv[i-1][0])' is a more concise way of writing a tradition if/else statement?

Comment: I did that in this case because based on `read_tsv[i][0] == read_tsv[i-1][0]` condition, you need to print `True or False`, so, I found easier to print the condition, since that condition are going to have one of these two values `True or False`.

Comment: you used 'i == 0' to signify the first list element.  'i == 0' would point to the first list element irregardless of the list length.  is there a way to signify the last list element that would work irregardless of the list length?

Comment: I just saw the comment. Yeah, the last element of a list is when  `i == len(mylist)-1`, for example:  `mylist=['a','b','c']`,   `mylist[len(mylist)-1]='c' ` .

Answer (score 0):

Add a new variable that stores the previous value and then simply perform your check against this variable. Assuming you only want to add a line if the first value is the same as in the row before:

```
import csv

#read the tsv into python, tell python its a tsv
tsv_file = open("tsv-test.txt")
read_tsv = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t")

#put tsv into a 2D array
arraytest = []
prev_row = ''
for line in read_tsv:
    if line[0] == prev_row
        arraytest.append(line)
    prev_row = line[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Just compare the current value to the last one read:

```
import csv

#read the tsv into python, tell python its a tsv
tsv_file = open("tsv-test.txt")
read_tsv = csv.reader(tsv_file, delimiter="\t")

#put tsv into a 2D array
arraytest = []
for line in read_tsv:
    if arraytest and line[0] == arraytest[-1][0]:
        # TODO: do something with the duplicate
        pass
    arraytest.append(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try enumerate to take advantage of using index.

```
read_tsv = open("tsv-test.txt").readlines()

arraytest = []
for idx,line in enumerate(read_tsv):
    if idx == 0:
        continue
    if read_tsv[idx].split()[0] == read_tsv[idx-1].split()[0]:
        arraytest.append(read_tsv[idx])

print(arraytest)
```